# How to DRY this validate_each method "foo" or "bar"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class CleanValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value .include? "foo" or "bar" or "baz" or "fiz"
      record.errors[attribute] << ("Restricted Word")
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to move the restricted words `"foo" or "bar" or "baz" or "fiz"` out of the method.

Comment: This validation doesn't do what you think it does. :) I bet you get a lot of "restricted word" errors.

Comment: I know "foo" will restrict "food" etc...

Comment: yeah, but if "foo" is not found, "bar" will restrict everything. Effectively, all your strings will be restricted.

Comment: You are correct. Please advise.

Comment: Ask another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533895/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-a-list-of-strings-to-be-used-in-a-validate-each-m thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only not DRY if you're repeating yourself. Are you using "foo" or "bar" or "baz" or "fiz" elsewhere? If not, or don't plan to, it might be over-coding to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. Move the restricted word list to a separate method and then test that the value is included in that array:

```
class CleanValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if restricted_words.include?(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << ("Restricted Word")
    end
  end

  def restricted_words
    ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'fiz']
  end
end
```

Comment: While you are on a right path, your code now does something _completely_ different, both from OP's actual code and intended one.

Comment: No, OP's code does not work correctly.  `value.include? "foo" or "bar" or "baz" or "fiz"` will always be truthy regardless of the value of value because `"foo" or "bar" or "baz" or "fiz"` always equals 'foo'.

Comment: True, hence the part "and intended one"

Comment: Yep, that's the problem, you didn't understand the intent. He wants to reject some strings (chat messages or whatever) if they contain stop words.