# What is the correct syntax for a list of strings to be used in a validate_each method to test if a value .include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code works currently, however, I would like to add more words to be tested besides "foo".

```
class CleanValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value .include? "foo" 
      record.errors[attribute] << ("Restricted Word")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common mistake is to chain words with a || operator. Something like this:

```
if value.include? "foo" || "bar" || "quux"
```

This won't work because it's equal to

```
if value.include?("foo" || "bar" || "quux")
```

which is equal to

```
if value.include?("foo")
```

other words are ignored because "foo" is always truthy.

An even worse mistake is to use `or` operator

```
if value.include? "foo" or "bar" or "quux"
```

it's equal to

```
if value.include?("foo") or "bar" or "quux"
```

So either "foo" is found, or "bar" evaluates to a truthy value. In either case, all other values are ignored.

A proper way would be to call `.include?` with **each** word

```
if value.include?('foo') || value.include?('bar') || value.include?('quux')
```

A slightly less repetitive way is to use [Enumerable.any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
restricted_words = ['foo', 'bar', 'quux']
if restricted_words.any?{|word| value.include?(word) }
```

Code style comments:

- DO NOT put a space before dot (as in `value .include?`). While syntactically correct, it looks very weird.
- DO NOT use `and` / `or` / `not` keywords. Ever. Use their better counterparts: && / || / !. Also, check out the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) (this point is covered there)

Comment: fwiw, Raven's code does not work unless I remove (.downcase) from it.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss: interesting. If anything, it should make the matches more reliable. "foo" will forbid "foo", "Foo" and "fOo". It _should_ work. Unless your `value` is an array and not a string.

Comment: I used this answer to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578542/setting-up-logging-out-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-controller-action-contains/

Answer (score 2):

I think a good solution would be:

```
class CleanValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  UNCLEAN_WORDS = %w(foo bar baz)
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if UNCLEAN_WORDS.any? { |word| value.downcase.include?(word) }
      record.errors[attribute] << ("Restricted Word")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Whew. Thanks, read the code a little too fast ;) Haha  too tired for this.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss: for the future, just a "does not work" is the most terrible way of reporting a problem. It brings no value or clues. At least, specify the error you're getting (if there is one) or provide the output and point out why you think it's wrong (if it works, but returns wrong output)

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss I assume that you mean it does not work if nil is passed? (would raise and NoMethodError) odr the value is not a string. To do these further checks this is completely individual, as this question asked for how to write multiple conditions for unallowed words.