# Setting up logging out...is there a way to check if a controller action contains a before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `before_action :logged_in_user` in my controller which redirects to the `login_path` if there is no `current_user`.

I am struggling with the logic of how to setup logout (destroy a session) in my app.

If a user is on a page where they are **not required** to be `logged_in?`, I want the logout just to `redirect_to :back` (stay on that page) since it does not effect the current page viewing.

If they are on a page that requires that they are `logged_in?`, I want them to be `redirect_to :root_url`, because otherwise they will be `redirect_to` the `login_path` which is awkward since they just logged_out.

So basically in pseudo code I want to do the following:

```
redirect_to :back 
   unless :back controller:action >> before_action :logged_in_user 
     then redirect_to root_url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SessionsController

  def destroy
    destroy_location
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_logout 
  end

  def destroy_location
    path = ["/feed", "/friends", "/saved_articles", "/favorites"]
    if path.any?{|word| URI(request.referrer).path == word }
      session[:exit] = root_url
    end      
  end  

  def redirect_logout 
    redirect_to(session[:exit] || :back)
    session.delete(:exit)
  end
```

This works rather nicely!